# Convert Auto Property to Notification Property (MVVM in WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, properties

Is there any way to convert Auto property to Notify Property automaticly?

`INotifyPropertyChanged`

Or any other way for MVVM in WPF

```
public string Filename { get; set; }
```

To

```
string _Filename;
public string Filename {
    get { return _Filename; }
    set {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            _Filename = value; 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Filename"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you on .Net 4.5?  Or older?

Comment: I'm on 4.0, is there any solution for 4.5????.

Comment: For 4.5 there's a nice solution using `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.  I don't know how to do this in 4.0. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [kindofmagic](http://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/) project that looks close to what you need.

It's an MSBuild task that processes your assemblies and adds `PropertyChanged` calls to the properties decorated with some `[Magic]` attribute. I've used it a bit and find extremely helpful.